# How do I access style properties of pseudo-elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, pseudo-element

For context, this is a followup to [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732409/how-can-i-improve-my-first-user-script). Rather than digging through `cssRules`, I'd like to base the logic on jQuery selectors that search for the *effects* of those rules.

Given default properties of

```
.commentarea .author:before {
    background-image: url(http://...);
    background-position: -9999px -9999px;
    /* ... */
}
```

that are selectively modified as in

```
.author[href$="gbacon"]:before /* ... */ {
  content: "";
  background-position: 0 -140px
}
```

how can I select pseudo-elements whose respective background positions have default values? Copying the selector as in

```
GM_log("size = " + $(".commentarea .author:before").size());
```

matches nothing. Trying [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) with

```
$(".commentarea .author")
  .map(function(i) {
         GM_log($(this)
                  .siblings()
                  .map(function (i) { return $(this).css("background-image") })
                  .get()
                  .join(", "))
       });
```

produces only `none` values.

For full details, see the [live page](http://www.reddit.com/r/CFB/comments/dahaz/get_your_team_logo_here_with_rules/). Is this possible?

Comment: So basically you want to select `.class1 .class2` as long as the elements' background image and position are the default (based on the CSS rule)?

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the HTML you are working with?

Comment: @SimpleCoder I want to select `.class1 .class2` as long as *the neighboring pseudo-element's* background position is the default.

Comment: @Greg Bacon; the `:before` and `:after` psuedo-elements are usually used to insert content (http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_pseudo_before.asp). Is the CSS selector working? I've never seen it used like this.

Comment: @Greg Bacon: I can still provide a solution however. By neighboring, do you mean in any direction?

Comment: Are you suere the CSS renders as expected?

Comment: @joberror See the [live page](http://www.reddit.com/r/CFB/comments/dahaz/get_your_team_logo_here_with_rules/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements like this. The purpose of them is to insert content before and after (respectively) the selector you have specified.

**Example usage:**

HTML:

```
<span class='a'>
    Outer
    <span class='b'>
        Inner
    </span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.a .b:before {
    content: "|Inserted using :before|";
}

.a {
    color: blue;
}

.b {
    color: red;
}
```

**Result:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mzcp6/

What happened was that the text `|Inserted using :before|` was inserted before (well, really, prepended into) the inner span because it was class `b` and a descendant of an element of class `a`. Basically, `:before` and `:after` don't select; they modify.

**Example:**

This doesn't work as expected:

HTML:

```
<span class='a'>
    <p>More text</p>
    <span class='b'>
        <p>More text</p>
        Inner
    </span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.a .b:before {
    text-size: 100px;
}
```

Nothing happens:

http://jsfiddle.net/bQ2ty/

**EDIT:**

`:before` is not a valid jQuery selector: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

I think you will need to use something other than `:before` or attempt to extract the original rule using the jQuery plugin: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/11/jqueryrule.html

Comment: I think it'll also be good to note that the content generated by `:before` and `:after` do not actually show up in the DOM (because they are purely presentational), thus, there really is no way to select them with jQuery.

Comment: @Yi Jiang - Precisely; I noticed that too but failed to mention it. Thank you.