# Select :after pseudo class/element

Tags: jquery, css

In CSS, I have used `body:after` to add content, I want to in jQuery get its height. How might I do that?

I read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743513/how-do-i-access-style-properties-of-pseudo-elements-with-jquery) such pseudo elements are for modifications and thus unselectable? I seem to be unable to even use `$("body > :last-child")` to select the last child which should be the `:after`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the content you add using `:after` and `content` isn't a [node](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_nodes.asp) - it isn't either an element nor text in your document. You can see this with FireBug: in this screenshot, my HTML contains the word "hello" but the word "world!" is added using CSS:

[image: Screenshot of a Hello World page where the word World is added with CSS content. FireBug is open, clearly showing that the CSS content does not add an element to the DOM]

What you can do is use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.getComputedStyle) to find out what the content is, like the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >
    <head>
        <title>Select :after pseudo class/element</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        #msg:after {
            content:" World!"
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            if(window.getComputedStyle) {
                var element = document.getElementById("msg");
                var style = window.getComputedStyle(element,':after')
                alert(style.content);
            }
            else {
                alert("This browser sucks!"); // ;)
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <span id="msg">Hello</span>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

... unfortunately, this gives you access to the *content* but not to the height :(

Comment: @MikeHometchko - Well I like you then, buddy! :D