# How to edit element created in CSS with :after using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-class

I have created an element in CSS with pseudo-class :after. Is there a way to change it's CSS properties from jQuery?

Comment: say what?  what do you have so far? vague much?

Comment: can you show us some html and the before and after css ?

Answer (score 1):

I thinks you want

```
$('#object_id:after').css({
  color: blue
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a little vague.  You can change the css properties of anything in the DOM by using the `css()` method, like so:

```
$('#my-thing').css({
  fontSize: 10em,
  width: 100px
});
```

If you're asking about getting something with the `:after` pseudoclass, refer to [this answered quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347690/select-after-pseudo-class-element)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks. So, it seems there is no way to manipulate the elements created in CSS using :after.

Comment: @z-x unfortunately, no it doesn't seem like this is possible at this time.  But you still haven't done a good job of explaining exactly what you want to do.