# How to change css :hover?

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access style properties of pseudo-elements with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743513/how-do-i-access-style-properties-of-pseudo-elements-with-jquery)

First,hover the block will rotation 40deg!!

How to change .block:hover from 40deg to 80deg  when click button ??

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">

.block{
    -moz-transition:All 1s ease;
    -moz-transform: rotate(1deg);

    width:200px; height:100px;
background-color:#999;
}
.block:hover{
    -moz-transform: rotate(40deg);
}

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="change">&raquo; Run</button><br><br>
<div class="block">TEST</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$("#change").click(function(){

//???

});
</script>
```

Comment: `:active { -moz-transform(80deg); }`?

Answer (score 1):

Change the class instead

```
<style type="text/css">

.block, .block-80{
    -moz-transition:All 1s ease;
    -moz-transform: rotate(1deg);

    width:200px; height:100px;
background-color:#999;
}
.block:hover{
    -moz-transform: rotate(40deg);
}
.block-80:hover{
    -moz-transform: rotate(80deg);
}

</style>
```

JS

```
<script>
$("#change").click(function(){

  $('.block').removeClass('block').addClass('block-80');

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class on click which have the required style, try this

```
.rotate80deg{
    -moz-transform: rotate(80deg);
}


$("#change").click(function(){

   $(this).addClass('rotate80deg');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by adding a class via jQuery.

Example:

*jQuery*

```
$('#change').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
});
```

*CSS*

```
.on {
    -moz-transform: rotate(80deg);
}
```

jsFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/XFPPn/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jquery addin that can help you with the transform property in css [jquery-css-transform](https://github.com/zachstronaut/jquery-css-transform)