# Change the background-position of :before CSS selector with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using [this](http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/jquery-javascript/jquery-fancy-custom-radio-and-checkbox/) for custom radio buttons and checkboxes, but I need to change the `:before` element's background on click. Is it possible?

HTML

```
<div class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="test">
</div>
```

CSS (its .less)

```
.checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;

    input { display: none; }

    &:before {
        background: url(/img/checkboxes.png) no-repeat;
        content: "";
        float: left;
        height: 18px;
        width: 19px;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your CSS has some mistakes. You can't put input & :before inside .checkbox. It needs to be a class of it's own.

Comment: @ComputerArts it is actually `less` which compiles to `css`

Comment: noted! missed that part! sorry!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743513/how-do-i-access-style-properties-of-pseudo-elements-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't select pseudo elements with jQuery, I'd say the cleanest solution is to manipulate the class of the element with jQuery:

```
.checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;

    input { display: none; }

    &:before {
        background: url(/img/checkboxes.png) no-repeat;
        content: "";
        float: left;
        height: 18px;
        width: 19px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    &.someclass:before {
      background-position:0 -55px;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
$('.checkbox').addClass('someclass');
```

Comment: Something like in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/S5McL/ (That's a neat way to mod :before, infensus!)