# jQuery/CSS selecting :before and :after pseudo-elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access style properties of pseudo-elements with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743513/how-do-i-access-style-properties-of-pseudo-elements-with-jquery)
>   [Manipulating CSS :before and :after pseudo-elements using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery)

I'm making an on/off switch and decided to try using the `:after` pseudo-element for the physical switch.  The styling is such that I just need to switch the pseudo element between float right and float left to switch it on and off.

Can I select pseudo-elements in jQuery or plain javascript?  I've tried `$("#myid:after")` and `$("#myid::after")`, both of which work in the stylesheet but are not working as jQuery selectors.

Or do I have to give in and use an extra div or span? That seems like it would be a pretty big drawback for pseudo elements.

Comment: Pseudo elements don't exist in the DOM, they can't be selected with JS. Use a `span` or similar.

Comment: Ahh sorry for the duplicate, thanks

Comment: FWIW a good workaround for my case in particular is to define both `#myid.on:after` and `#myid.off:after` in my stylesheet and then just add/remove the classes "on" and "off" on the switch div.

Comment: danny do you have any demo?