# How to change the colour of pseudo-elements in CSS through JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have made a heart-shaped button using CSS. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/helxsz/npMyy/) is the JSFiddle link of my code.

```css
#heart {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
#heart .outline:before,
#heart .outline:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 28px;
  top: 1px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 27px;
  background: #d53423;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  border-radius: 85px 60px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
#heart .outline:after {
  left: 13px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 45px 60px 0 0;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
$("#heart").on('submit',
function(e) {
  console.log('click heart support');
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#heart .outline:before').css('background', 'grey');
}
);
```

```html
<form id="heart">
  <button id="like_btn" class="outline" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

When I click the form button, I want this heart-shaped button to change its colour. However, this heart-shaped button is made from CSS pseudo-elements and hence, I can't easily change its colour.

Does anyone have a clue as to how can I manipulate CSS pseudo-elements (e.g. `:before` and `:after`) using JQuery?

Comment: It can't be done with jQuery - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743513/how-do-i-access-style-properties-of-pseudo-elements-with-jquery

Comment: Add a class instead. Better to keep all styling in the CSS anyway.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I set `:before` `:after` background color inherit, then change the background color of their parent. http://jsfiddle.net/npMyy/3/

```
.outline {
    background: red;
}
#heart .outline:before, #heart .outline:after {
    background: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work for me (Firefox 20)... not tested in anything else..

```
#heart .outline:active:before,
#heart .outline:active:after {
    background: #000;
}
```

Here, `:active` is a pseudo-class, and `:before` and `:after` are pseudo-elements. So this is perfectly acceptable according to [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-classes).

> Pseudo-classes are allowed anywhere in selectors while pseudo-elements may only be appended after the last simple selector of the selector.

Comment: The css part clearly works, the problem of the asker is changing the colour AFTER, with jQuery... which is not working... :)

Comment: In that case give the element another class using jQuery onlick - then style it differently... I will try and make a jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Another sol'n would be to change your form's class on submit and target the heart child's `:before` and `:after` with the modified selector. **Though I do REALLY like N A T H's answer using `:active`.** sxy. Just made minimal changes to your existing code.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/npMyy/23/)

## jquery

```
$("#heart:not(.submitted)").on('submit',function(e){
    console.log('click heart support');     
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#heart').addClass('submitted');
});
```

## css

```
// ... removed lines 

#heart.submitted .outline:before,
#heart.submitted .outline:after{
    background: grey;
}
```

## html

```
<form id="heart" >
    <button id="like_btn" class="outline" type="submit" ></button>
</form>
```