# JQuery change 'top' of :after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the 'top' attribute of :after in an element.

CSS:

```
.mymessage:after
{
top:20px;
}
```

How can I animate it to say, 40px?

Comment: Impossible with jquery

Comment: You can set the style of a pseudo element by directly appending CSS into the `head` between style tags, not sure about animating.

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3743612/684932

Comment: http://jsbin.com/atujef/1/edit

Answer (score 4):

Pseudoelements aren't part of the DOM, so in principle they are inaccessible with Javascript. The best you can do is add a stylesheet to your page that adds a new rule for the pseudoelement.

Answer (score 0):

You could get jquery to add a class to the element `$('.mymessage').addClass('active')` then create styles for that and set css animations

```
.mymessage:after
{
top:20px;
-webkit-transition: all .25s linear;
-moz-transition: all .25s linear;
-ms-transition: all .25s linear;
-o-transition: all .25s linear;
transition: all .25s linear;
}

.mymessage.active:after
{
top:40px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help with animation?

Comment: The animation is taken care of by the CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/LGg69/