# How can I get an element's font size with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-size

How can I get the actual font-size of the #t1 element? It is obviously 26px but in all the browsers I get 16px.

```
<div class="editor">Hello <span id="t1">my</span><br>dear <span id="t2">world</span></div>

<button id="test">TEST</button>

<style>
.editor
{
    font-size: 16px;
}
.editor:first-line
{
    font-size: 26px;
}
</style>

<script>
$('#test').click(function()
{
    alert( $('#t1').css('font-size') + ' vs ' + $('#t2').css('font-size') );    
});
</script>
```

[Demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4na0nbk/)

Comment: This should help you http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Why is there a need to get the actual font-size in the first place? Just for some HTML/CSS teaching game of some sort? Rather than reading out the styling I would use classes and data- attributes to help with the behavior part while the CSS is just made to fit that.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in your style:

```
.editor{
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

This line sets `font-size` to all its child tags thats why it always give 16

instead of

```
.editor:first-line{
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

This user needs to write

```
#t1{
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

it will give you the perfect size.

Comment: But the problem is: I cannot change the CSS nor the HTML. All browsers render the very first line of  the .editor element in 26px but return 16px.

Comment: okay.. if u just want to set the size then u can write simple $('#t1').css('font-size','26px'); ans same for t2

Comment: Thank you, but that won't help here. The element #t1 can be placed anywhere in the .editor by visitor of my site (using Javascript). And then I need to be able to tell the font-size of the element.

Answer (score 1):

The question here is - How to get style from a pseudo element.

```
var fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('.editor'), ':first-line'
    ).getPropertyValue('font-size');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/troythompson/mrz3uh8x/

http://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element

[How do I access style properties of pseudo-elements with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743513/how-do-i-access-style-properties-of-pseudo-elements-with-jquery)

Comment: Not exactly. I just want to get font-size of #t1 element. It can be anywhere in the DOM. What if the visitor moves it to the second line of .editor? I will have to add some special handling of such cases. Seems all the browsers ARE buggy and there is NO way to get real font-size of an element without complicated tricks.

Comment: Why is firstline being used? Why do you need to retrieve  the style of a pseudo element?