# jQuery show content in :after when certain DIV is found in document

Tags: jquery, find

I have user reviews tab on our shop and put image to this in `.tab:after`just to make it more visible. But I want to show this content only when there already is any user review.

Why my code doesn't work?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('.review').length) { 
      $(".tab:after").css("display", "block");
    } 
    else { 
      $(".tab:after").css("display", "none"); 
    }
});
</script>
```

**[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2y2htkjd/)**

**EDIT:** Thank you all! This does the magic:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('.review').length >0) { 
        $(".tab").addClass('show-it')
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.tab:after {
    display:none;
    }
.tab.show-it:after {
    display:block;
    }
```

Comment: Adding html will make it easy to find out the problem

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743513/how-do-i-access-style-properties-of-pseudo-elements-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `".tab:after"` selector will return an empty set as jQuery and JavaScript in general can't select/manipulate CSS pseudo elements. You can use a class, toggle it and leave the manipulation to CSS.

```
.tab.block:after {
    display: block;
    ...
}
```

```
$(".tab").toggleClass("block", $(".review").length > 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzefrbvr/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('.review').length >0) { 
      $(".tab:after").css("display", "block");
    } 
    else { 
      $(".tab:after").css("display", "none"); 
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove `:after`. See the link below

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19ut0xpb/)

Comment: But then the whole tab would be hidden!

Comment: The review div if available will contain the tab div where you are adding some images. And when the review div is not available it should hide the tab div. Is that right?

Comment: No it should hide tab's :after. I solved it, check edited OP.